# Unable to see the data from my USB after removing vbs.helper and installer.vbs files

Tags: vbscript, cmd, usb-drive

I've removed the files named `vbs.helper` and `installer.vbs` from Windows USB infected and now I can't see my folder. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I tried using `attrib` command in Windows, but it didn't work:

```
attrib -r -a -s -h
```

[image: Pendrive properties]

Comment: You're referencing Windows Command Prompt, right?

Comment: yes i use a virtualbox

Comment: but not show im triying to see with nautilus in propierties appear the data space used but in folder dont apperas nothing

Comment: yes i prove this command but not works i see that propierties contain data but dont show

Comment: yes in my windows virtual box windows sp3 i try this but dont appears nothing

Comment: this is confuse because i deleted this hidden script using linux

Comment: Just clarifying this, by show system files, I mean by going into file explorer options and unchecking "Don't show hidden files, folders, or drive".

Comment: yes i do this in options carpet show hidden  folders dont show

Comment: No, not show hidden folders. There's another option for system files. You go to file explorer, view, Options, view, and check "show hidden files, folders, and drives".

Comment: Assuming by carpet, you mean the "ribbon" or whatever it's called...

Comment: http://techzend.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/show-hidden-files.png

Comment: you refear this

Comment: yes this script are cross platform i dont know how open my files

Comment: I don't know. I went ahead and up-voted your question. Hopefully someone with a similar experience can help you out. I remember doing something similar to this, but I've always been able to undo it at any moment. Good luck.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem using qphotorec and ddrescue   ; thank for all

https://sourceforge.net/projects/crunchyiconthem/files/QPhotoRec/